# Detecting implicit casts in a Roslyn diagnostic analyzer

Tags: c#, roslyn

I want to create a Roslyn diagnostic analyzer to find implicit casts, specifically constructs like:

```
DateTimeOffset v = new DateTime();
```

This means that I either have to detect implicit casts, or find references to `DateTimeOffset.op_Implicit(DateTime)`.

The problem though is that Roslyn diagnostic analyzers work on syntax, not the semantic model. So, the only approach I can think of is to figure out all syntax constructs that could potentially have an implicit cast in them, and run semantic analysis on those. This however is pretty tricky since even if I would be able to create an exhaustive list of syntax constructs that can generate an implicit cast, changes to the language can easily introduce new ones.

My question is whether there is an alternative approach to the one described above. **Specifically, is it possible to write a Roslyn diagnostic analyzer that runs against the semantic model?** Or have I missed something and are there better alternatives than what I described above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're incorrect here:

> The problem though is that Roslyn diagnostic analyzers work on syntax, not the semantic model.

You can register diagnostic analyzers to work against the syntax, or the semantic model, or the even higher level "operation" kind. For example, Kasey Uhlenhuth has an [example](https://github.com/kuhlenh/demofodder/blob/master/IOperationZeroSizeArrayAnalyzer_End/ZeroSizeArrayAnalyzer/ZeroSizeArrayAnalyzer/DiagnosticAnalyzer.cs) detecting the creation of zero-length arrays.

You can call `AnalysisContext.RegisterSemanticModelAction` or `AnalysisContext.RegisterOperationAction`. You may well want to register for operations with an operation kind of `Conversion` - that would probably remove a lot of the work.

Comment: I've tried this and it works perfectly. Only problem I encountered was that the project template in Visual Studio uses an old Roslyn dependency, which wouldn't work in VS2017. Updating the NuGet packages solved this.

Comment: @PietervanGinkel Could you share your solution please? I've just started with Roslyn and I can't figure out how to do it. :\

Answer (score 1):

@Tudvari
Something like this

```
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class DoNotCastIQueryableImplicitlyAnalyzer : CodeAnalyzerBase
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override string Identifier => "RULE123";

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override string Title => "Do not cast IQueryable to IEnumerable implicitly";

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override string Message => "Do not cast IQueryable to IEnumerable implicitly. Use explicit materialization if needed. {0}";

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override EnCategory Category => EnCategory.Usage;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void RegisterActions(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.RegisterOperationAction(AnalyzeOperationAction, OperationKind.Conversion);
    }
    
    private void AnalyzeOperationAction(OperationAnalysisContext context)
    {
        if (context.Operation is not IConversionOperation
            {
                Operand.Type.Name: nameof(IQueryable<object>),
                Type.Name: nameof(IEnumerable<object>),
                Conversion.IsImplicit: true
            })
        {
            return;
        }

        var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(
            DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticSeverity.Warning),
            conversionOperation.Syntax.GetLocation(), 
            conversionOperation.Operand.Syntax.ToString());
        
        context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is that construct in the starting `if` of `AnalyzeOperationAction()`? I've never seen this.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**